# Percentages and rounding in Python

Tags: python, rounding

I have a code which creates a list of percentage abundance of certain word lengths in a text file e.g. 1 letter words appear 13% of the time, what I was wondering is if there was 1 twenty letter word in a 50,000 word text file, would it round the percentage for twenty letter words down to 0 or up to 1?

here is the entire code:

```
lines = open ('E:\Videos, TV etc\Python\Assessment\dracula.txt', 'r'). readlines ()

stripped_list = [item.strip() for item in lines]

tally = [0] * 20

print tally #original tally

for i in stripped_list:
    length_word = int(len(i))
    tally[length_word-1] += 1 #adds 1 to the tally for the index of that word length, (length_word)-1 used as the tally for 1 letter words are in the 0 index
print tally

new_tally = [] #this tally will contain the occurences of each word length by percentage
for a in tally:
    new_tally.append((100*a)/(sum(tally))) # multiplies by 100 and divides by all of the tallies to give a percentage
print new_tally
```

Comment: In order to answer that question, we'd need to see how you are calculating your percentages and how the rounding is being done.

Comment: It's hard to say for sure unless you post the code.

Comment: It is completely dependent on what is doing the rounding.  Are you using `print "%.2f" % value` or some sort of string formatting?

Comment: Ok, I'll post the entire code in the question for you :)

Comment: Ah thanks for the clarification, however I don't need a float value as I need to plot a histogram with one * for each percentage point, I was just wondering out of interest, thanks again. :D

Comment: i'd calculate percentage on float value and then and then round them down or truncate, whichever that fits. `percentage = 100*round(float(cnt)/float(all))`, something like this.  That keep records of which method you took, rounding or truncating.   just my thought.

Answer (score 3):

By default you got truncated number, if both numerator and denominator are integer.

```
>>> 1 / 50000
0
```

to work around and real percentage, you change one or both of value to be floating poing number

```
>>> 1.0 / 50000
2e-05
```

And in case you are talking about variables,

```
>>> cnt, all = 1, 50000
>>> float(cnt) / all
2e-05
```

multiply 100 to yield percentage.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is using integer floor division which always rounds towards zero.

Get more control by using floating point division and Python's [round()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round) builtin function:

```
percentage = round((100.0*a) / sum(tally))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using int(), then Python *always* rounds down. int(0.99999) = 0. It's literally just dropping the part after decimal.

If you want something more like what most people mean by rounding, you can do:
   "%0.0f" % (yourval,).

That uses an algorithmn, the name of which escapes me, where numbers exactly in the middle round towards the nearest *even* number, so 0.5 becomes 0, but 1.5 becomes 2. 0.49 is always 0, and 0.51 is always 1.

Answer (score 2):

It would round the answer down to 0.